# Connect using Windows ssh to another windows

Tags: windows-10, ssh

Is there any way to connect using ssh, from one pc with windows to another windows? , I have a user A on a PC and another user B, I try to connect from B to A using

> ssh [user-a] @ [host]

however when entering credentials these are not accepted, and probe with several users, and look for information about it however I can not find an answer, I do not know if I'm missing something, because when I connect with a remote desktop, I do not have any problems.

EDIT:
Windows users are on different computers, in which I also have ubuntu bash, and I connect via ssh between them (from ubuntu bash session to another session of ubuntu bash without problems), what I want is to connect from one session of windows to another , nevertheless I am not sure if it is the user or the password that does not allow me to connect, I have created new users and I still get the wrong password.
I have OpenSSH installed and the sshd service running.

Comment: do you have OpenSSH-Client and/or Server installed?

Comment: Are A and B on the same computer?  It isn't clear whether you're talking about separate computers or separate instances on the same machine.

Comment: What software you running as SSH server ? Keep in mind that user's names in ssh are case sensitive (at least in cygwin).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  `ssh user@host` indicates a user on the host.

Comment: I have tried on the same computer and different computer (since in linux I can connect to a ssh session while on the same computer)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.   Edit your question to indicate if you have the OpenSSH client installed on both machines and OpenSSH Server on the machine you want to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

[Use putty.exe](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-)

> PuTTY is the most popular app for connecting to SSH servers on
>   Windows. It’s completely open source and is even available as a
>   portable app, so you can add it to your portable app toolkit and use
>   it anywhere. PuTTY’s interface may seem a bit intimidating and
>   complicated at first, but it’s fairly simple once you start using it.
>
> PuTTY offers more power and options than the other SSH clients above,
>   running as a Windows desktop application. Like FireSSH, PuTTY also
>   offers SSH tunneling features. To use PuTTY, all you really need to do
>   is launch putty.exe, enter the hostname (or IP address) of the remote
>   server, ensure the port is correct, and click Open. PuTTY will connect
>   to the server and prompt you for a username and password. You can also
>   save this session information if you like — click the Default Settings
>   option and click Save and PuTTY will use your saved settings every
>   time it opens.
>
> All of these options are available on the main configuration pane. You
>   probably don’t need to touch any of the other options. If you want to
>   set up SSH tunneling in PuTTY, you’ll find the option under Connection
>   -> SSH ->  Tunnels.

And you can [have a look at this => 4-easy-ways-to-use-ssh-in-windows/](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-easy-ways-to-use-ssh-in-windows/)

For a ssh server for windows there is a commercial application called [tectia-ssh](https://www.ssh.com/products/tectia-ssh/)

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/#sec-What-if-you-don-39-t-have-a-server

You can install oracle Virtualbox on Windows and install a guest Linux like ubuntu. There it is easy to run a ssh server.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Installing VirtualBox and extension packs:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing

Ubuntu page and download pages.........[here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Install ssh: http://linux-sys-adm.com/how-to-install-and-configure-ssh-on-ubuntu-server-14.04-lts-step-by-step/

```
Step 1 – Update repositories.
root@mail:/# apt-get update
root@mail:/# apt-get upgrade

Step 2 – Install SSH Server
root@mail:/# apt-get install openssh-server

Basic Configuration

Step 3 – After installation I will show how to configure ssh server. Open ssh config file with the following command:
root@mail:/# nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Step 4 – If you want to change ssh port you have to find ‘Port’ line and change the number of the port. For example I will change to 22222.
Port 22222

Step 5 – I will set max login attempts to be 3. After 3 wrong login attempts you will disconect. This is very important for security of your server and this can be used for prevention from brute force attack (see my Theme 4). Add this line bellow Port:
MaxAuthTries 3

Step 6 – Allow certain users to login on your server and deny all other users. I will add ‘zimbra’ users because my Zimbra Mail Serve should have access. For more information about Zimbra Mail Server configuration read theme 12. Add the following line at the end of the file and after that save the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
AllowUsers mslavov zimbra

Step 7 – Restart ssh service with the following command:
root@mail:/# service ssh restart

Now only this two users will have access to your server.
```

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

**On the putty page there is a free ssh-server name bitvise-server, I haven't tried it but that could solve the issue.........**https://www.putty.org/

https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-download

> Bitvise SSH Server: Secure file transfer and terminal shell access for
>   Windows Screenshots
>
> Our SSH server supports all desktop and server versions of Windows,
>   32-bit and 64-bit, from Windows XP SP3 and Windows Server 2003, up to
>   the most recent – Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016.
>
> Bitvise SSH Server supports the following SSH services:
>
> ```
> Secure remote access via console (vt100, xterm and bvterm supported)
> Secure remote access via GUI (Remote Desktop or WinVNC required)
> Secure file transfer using SFTP and SCP (compatible with all major clients)
> Secure, effortless Git integration
> Secure TCP/IP connection tunneling (port forwarding)
> ```
>
> You can try out Bitvise SSH Server risk-free. To begin, simply
>   download the installation executable - you will find the download
>   links on our download page. After installing, you are free to evaluate
>   Bitvise SSH Server for up to 30 days. If you then decide to continue
>   using it, purchase a license.
>
> When the personal edition is chosen during installation, Bitvise SSH
>   Server can be used free of charge by non-commercial personal users.

Comment: I know that with putty I can connect to a session ssh, I have always used it to connect from windows to linux, however I can not connect to a session from windows to windows using putty or any tool.

Comment: @KevinDanielMendozaVásquez see my update

Comment: I do not need to install virtualbox, I know I can connect from a s.o windows to a linux s.o easily, the problem is that I want to connect from a pc with s.o windows to another pc with s.o windows using ssh.

Comment: @KevinDanielMendozaVásquez look at the end of the answer bitvise-ssh server free for non-commercial use

Comment: I will try it, however I already have openssh server installed.

Comment: @KevinDanielMendozaVásquez what, which is it, you needed ssh-server(openssh) or you don't, what's the point of answering if you say you don't need it, why did you ask